# Generic BaseFragment to verify implemented interface for callback

Tags: java, android

I'm having a BaseFragment like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<C> extends Fragment {

    protected C callback;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
    public void onAttach(final Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            this.callback = (C) getActivity();
        } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement " + this.callback.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}
```

I have an implementation fragment:

```
public class MainFragment<C extends MainFragment.Callback> extends BaseFragment<C> {
    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        MainFragment<Callback> fragment = new MainFragment<>();
        return fragment;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void doSomething();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I create the fragment with the newInstance static method. 
When I put a breakpoint in the onAttach it never fails and my activity is not even implementing the callback.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

What does it mean?
Generics classes exist only at compile-time. At runtime, you can consider every instance of your generic class as if it was an instance of `Object` class.

Your class at runtime will look like this:

```
protected Object callback;

@Override
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public void onAttach(final Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        this.callback = (Object) getActivity();
    } catch (final ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement " + this.callback.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

So you don't get any exception because `getActivity()` returns an Activity which is an `Object` instance